# Concatenating fields while also replacing values within certain stings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, field-calculator, vbscript

I am trying to use python to concatenate multiple fields in a polygon layer. Specifically, I am attempting to combine the values of four fields into one:

EXPCODE =

```
!MATRIX! & !PLANT! & !PCT! & !SITE!
```

This function seems straightforward to me, however, I would like to replace characters withing the MATRIX field. A few examples of a MATRIX value would be:

```
H3C
H4A
CS4B
HS4D
```

After concatenating the EXPCODE field, I need to then write a replace function where all MATRIX "A" and "B" values are combined (H4B becomes H4AB).

Can anyone help me write this as one fluent function? I know I posted this as a python question, but if you are more comfortable with helping me using VBScript I am fine with that.

Comment: This one looks suitable for the Python Parser of Field Calculator rather than a separate Python script.  I think you should focus on getting the concatenation working in the ArcGIS Field Calculator first (here at [gis.se]), and then solving the replacement secondarily (probably searching [so] since that is pure Python).

Comment: Could you give a more specific example? I'm not really following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using field calculator (or, `arcpy.management.CalculateField()` if you want):

In the code block:

```
def fix_matrix(field_value):

    if field_value.endswith("A") or field_value.endswith("B"):
        return field_value[:-1]+"AB"
    else:
        return field_value
```

In the expression:

```
fix_matrix(!MATRIX!) + !PLANT! + !PCT! + !SITE!
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken me so long to reply. mr.adam your answer worked perfectly, thanks you!